# nested anchor texts in html5

Tags: html

I know that nesting of anchor tags is not allowed in HTML 4 ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)). I am not so sure however about [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

I understand that an `<a>` element without an `href` attribute is not a link. So are nested anchors valid if the inner ones are fo not have `href` attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Interactive content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#interactive-content-0) is defined as:

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>
> a audio (if the controls attribute is present) button details embed iframe img (if the usemap attribute is present) input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen label object (if the usemap attribute is present) select textarea video (if the controls attribute is present)

You will note that some of those elements have conditions. The `a` element does not. (i.e. it says "a" not "a (if the href attribute is present)".

So it is not valid to nest a elements at all.